# Userform will not activate after Shell command

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In Excel VBA I first open a photo in windows photo viewer (with the shell command), then open a userform for users to enter information. The problem is that I can find no way of activating the userform such that it's ready to type in after the photo has been displayed.

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & PicPath, vbNormalNoFocus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
AppActivate Application.Caption
UserForm1.Show vbModal
```

This code results in the userform appearing and being visible but not active. If the user presses keys, no text appears in the userform's textbox (I've done textbox1.setfocus when the form is initialised).

I'm not sure what the problem is. If I run the code without opening the picture then of course the userform is active and the user can start typing as soon as it appears with out having to click on it. But of course that's not a solution.

Edit: Adding minimal reproducible example

In the sub it's like this:

```
Public filename1 as String
Sub test()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim fullFP As String

folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New folder\"
filename1 = "Helicobacter.jpg"
fullFP = folderPath & filename1

Shell "explorer.exe " & fullFP, vbNormalNoFocus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
AppActivate Application.Caption
UserForm1.Show vbModal

End Sub
```

in the userform initialise sub it's this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ComboBox1.SetFocus

Label1.Caption = filename1

ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B" & 429).Value

ComboBox1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

and the problem is that after running the script the user presses keys and nothing appears in the combobox because it's not properly activated

Comment: Maybe try `AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"` rather than `AppActivate Application.Caption`

Comment: Also, since userforms are perfectly able to display images, why use explorer.exe at all? That seems like a baroque way to structure the code.

Comment: @John Coleman `AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"` leads to 'Invalid procedure call or argument'. You're right about displaying images in the form itself. I'm hoping to fix what I have rather than spending time going down that route.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I created a mock userform and it has the focus after running your code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnColeman. I've edited the original post with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Your code does not allow me to reproduce the problem. If you create a new workbook with the only code in the workbook the code that you have posted (and a userform with simply a label and combobox, with default properties), does it have the same bug? I did just that, and it ran as expected.

Comment: @JohnColeman I did the same. The picture comes up, but when I press letters on the keyboard they don't appear in the combobox because the userform is not selected. Are you sure you haven't clicked on the userform before entering letters? I have to either Alt+Tab or click on the user form before I can input writing.

Comment: Absolutely positive that the combobox has the focus after your code is run. What if you increase the time delay (and perhaps experiment with the optional `wait` parameter for `AppActivate`)?

Comment: @JohnColeman It definitely isn't working on my system. Picture comes up but cannot type in the combobox. Guess I'll just switch to including the pic in the userform itself. Thanks for your help